# SQL 2016 Format json not showing the 24 hour clock

Tags: sql-server, json, sql-server-2016

I have a Json column and when I format the date time, it does not identify the AM/PM

here is the right example.

```
    SELECT FORMAT(CAST(JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.exittime') AS datetimeoffset), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'),JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.exittime')
      FROM [dbTorontoTrader2016].[dbo].[Trades]
      where _id =6433
      you can see that
```

2016-08-18T15:13:47.9386882-04:00 
    shows as
     2016-08-18 03:13:47
 when it should be 2016-08-18 15:13:47
The actual Json is

```
       {  
   "direction":"Long",
   "entryprice":0.86282,
   "exitprice":0.86289,
   "potentialtarget":0.0004,
   "entrytime":"2016-08-18T13:41:46.5818618-04:00",
   "exittime":"2016-08-18T15:13:47.9386882-04:00",
   "maxfavourable":0.0008,
   "maxagainst":-0.0001,
   "maxagainst1ATR":-0.0001,
   "maxagainst2ATR":-0.0001,
   "gains":0.0001,
   "signal":"EnterLongFirstBreakout",
   "instrument":"$EURGBP",
   "account":"InteractiveBrokersindicatorbased",
   "quantity":1,
   "hitedge":true,
   "RealizedProfitLoss":0.0,
   "CashValue":0.0,
   "BuyingPower":0.0
}
```

  

Comment: What is your question? Why it is converting 00:40 to 12:40? How to get the letters AM/PM to showup?  Also, why do you think 01:28:10 should be a PM time? ISO8601 says otherwise.

Comment: how can i make 2016-08-18T01:28:10.1565142-04:00 show as 2016-08-18 13:28:10

Comment: why would 01:28:10 become 13:28:10?

Comment: updated the example to reflect the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

when I changed from hh to HH it fixed my problem

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.exittime') AS datetimeoffset), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.exittime')
  FROM [dbTorontoTrader2016].[dbo].[Trades]
  where _id =6433

(No column name)    (No column name)
2016-08-18 15:13:47 2016-08-18T15:13:47.9386882-04:00
```

Comment: FORMAT can be gross.  This works too: 
CAST(cast(JSON_VALUE(trade, '$.exittime') AS datetimeoffset) AS DATETIME2(0))